# Separate event in control

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouseover, visualstatemanager

I'm wondering if I can have a individual component in a control have an event. For example, I've created my own control, and with VisualStateManager I'm able to handle several events that fire for the control as a whole, I'd like just my togglebutton in the controlto fire the mouseover event. Currently any area of the control that the mouse is over fires the mouseover which ruins the coloranimation effect i'm trying to get, I want the coloranimation to only happen when the toggle button has a mouse over, my control has a contentpresent allowing for other content, i don't want that piece to fire the event.

Example of what i'm talking about below in generic.xaml file.

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">

                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!-- This fires for any part of the control, is it possible to just create a mouseover for the ToggleButton below? -->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Margin="3">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="1" x:Name="ExpandCollapseButton">

                                </ToggleButton>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="Content">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob, You can access the togglebutton from your class like this:

ToggleButton myToggleButton = GetTemplateChild("toggleButton") as ToggleButton;

Create the events you want in your class. You may need to override the OnApplyTemplate method and create your event there, I'm still researching this part and don't fully understand it yet, you will have to play with it. I did override my OnApplyTemplate and it worked for me.

```
ToggleButton myToggleButton;
public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    myToggleButton = GetTemplateChild("toggleButton") as ToggleButton;
    myToggleButton.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(myToggleButton_MouseEnter);
}
void myToggleButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MouseEnter", true);
    }
```

Also make sure to setup your Template at the top:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "MouseEnter", GroupName = "ViewStates")]
```

The VisualState can exist in the generic.xaml file where you are setting up your other visualstates and does not need to be in the inner ToggleButton.

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseEnter">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="toggleButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.SomeProperty).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="SomeColor"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all lets get our terminology correct, you are not talking about "events" you are talking about "visual states".   The "MouseOver" is a visual state.  Its the responsibility of code within the control to decide which of the visual states the control is in.

Ordinarily code in the control will use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to set a boolean to indicate that the mouse is over the control and then call some `UpdateStates` method in which the developer will include logic to determine which visual states the control ought to be in currently.

In your case rather than using the controls `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events attach these handlers to your inner `ToggleButton` instead.

Comment: Do you mean add visualstates to the inner togglebutton?

Comment: @Bob: No I meant that you need to write code and attach that code as event handlers to the MouseEnter and MouseLeave __events__ of the `ToggleButton`.  This code will use `VisualStateManager.GotoState` to specify what visual state your control should be in.  I'm curious at how this confusion is arising, what base class does `MyControl` derive from?